# Why does the number of tuples selected vary in these queries

Tags: sql, oracle11g, rdbms

I am new to DBMS and SQL. While practicing some basic queries i had come across this doubt.

Suppose this query's result is null:`select * from table2 b where b.age>50;` i.e. there is no age in table2 greater than 50.

Why does a query like `select * from table1 a where a.age> all(select b.age from table2 b where b.age>50);`  select all the tuples in `table1`

Whereas a query: `select * from table1 a where a.age> any(select b.age from table2 b where b.age>50);`  selects 0 tuples.

What is the logic behind these (probably from the point of view of the SQL interpreter)?

Comment: In the second & third queries, the subquery should look like `select b.age from` instead of `select * from`.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks. corrected

Comment: Tell us why they should be the same or how you are stuck understanding an authoritative introduction or reference. Otherwise you are just asking us to write yet another presentation of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [documented behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Comparison-Conditions.html#GUID-828576BF-E606-4EA6-B94B-BFF48B67F927).

For `ANY` (or `SOME`), with emphasis added:

> Compares a value to each value in a list or returned by a query. Must be preceded by =, !=, >, <, <=, >=. Can be followed by any expression or subquery that returns one or more values.
>
> **Evaluates to FALSE if the query returns no rows.**

For `ALL`:

> Compares a value to every value in a list or returned by a query. Must be preceded by =, !=, >, <, <=, >=. Can be followed by any expression or subquery that returns one or more values.
>
> **Evaluates to TRUE if the query returns no rows.**

As the subquery gets no rows, it is therefore expected that the `ANY` version evaluates to false, since

```
select * from table1 a where a.age> all(select b.age from table2 b where b.age>50);
```

evaluates as (ignoring that you can't explicitly have true/false):

```
select * from table1 a where false; -- or more legally: where 1=0
```

and so returns no rows;

But the the `ALL` condition evaluates to true, since

```
select * from table1 a where true; -- or more legally: where 1=1
```

and so returns all rows.

Answer (score 1):

`select * from table1 a where a.age > all(select b.age from table2 b where b.age>50);`

Your first query takes each record from `table1`, then checks whether or not `age` is greater than *all* results from the sub-query. Since the sub-query has no results, this is always true.

`select * from table1 a where a.age > any(select b.age from table2 b where b.age>50);`

Your second query takes each record from `table1`, then checks whether or not `age` is greater than *any* result from the sub-query. Since the sub-query has no results, this is never true.